# Aspect ratio of FSPDFViewCtrl

Tags: ios, foxit, foxit-reader, foxitembeddedsdk

Do you know a way to fetch the aspect ratio of a PDF loaded into `FSPDFViewCtrl`? I could not find any appropriate methods or properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since aspect ratios can differ from page to page, it's only possible to fetch the ratio **of a specific page** by dividing its width by its height:

```
let ratio = page.getWidth() / page.getHeight()
```